# Control not displaying data while Hosted on Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, devexpress, hosting

Actually,I have a `DevExpress ASPxMemo` control to show large data.
Now,I'm getting `500k` emails from `DB` and attaching them to `Memo` control by separating them with a `,`.
The problem here is that :
I'm able to display that Text in my `LocalMachine` and everything works fine.
But,while hosting that on server(`Windows Server 2012`),the Text is not getting bound(shown).

My code :

```
Int64 ListGroupID = Convert.ToInt64(VW_cmbToEmail.SelectedItem.Value);
string EmailIDS = "";
var dataLists = (from xx in VDC.SURVEY_EMAIL_LIST
                 where xx.EMAIL_GROUP_ID == ListGroupID
                 select xx.EMAILID).ToList();
EmailIDS = string.Join(",", dataLists.Select(x => x)); 
VW_MemoToEmailSingles.Text = EmailIDS;
```

Do anyone know about this?

Comment: Does the server have access to your database? Did you change the database connection string when you moved to 'production?'

Comment: ya..actually,I'm getting the data...but after binding to the control,it is not showing...it worked with 20000 records also..but for 5 lakh records it is not working